# PHP returns different then in objective-c

Tags: php, objective-c, ios

In php this line

```
      for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1,1);
        echo $keychar;
    }
returns `70684292517 `
```

And if i make the equivalent of this in objective-c it returns a whole different value.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        NSString *_keychar = [key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange((i % key.length)-1,1)];
//The fix
NSString *_keychar = [key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(((i % key.length) ? (i % key.length) : (key.length) )-1,1)];
        NSLog(@"%@",_keychar);
    }

    returns `068429251`
```

So, why isn't the obj-c code returning the same value as the php one(how it should be)?
What am i doing wrong?
string has a length of 11 and the key has a value of 0684292517

FIXED

Comment: The problem is that `0 % n` in PHP returns `n` and in Obj-C returns `0`

so please make sure to start the for loop from `1` as **0 % n** is not somethign that you usually want to use but Obj-C is the right one.

Comment: Mahmoud Fayer, interesting to know, thnx! But how does the for loop in obj-c needs to be right now? if i change i = 1;  and string.length+1 the substring check will go out of bounds.